# When will the population of a sample double (using dif-eq)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponential-function

I have the initial equation $$\frac{dP}{dt}=kp$$ where P is the population, t is time, and k is some positive constant. The rest of what I'm given is that P(0) = A, what is the time for the population to double its value?

Now, I've tried doing this in many possible ways but none of them get me to one of the answer choices.
$$ A: {\frac{k}{ln(2)}}$$ $$B: \frac{ln(k)}{2}$$ $$C: \frac{ln(2)}{k}$$ $$D: 2A$$
And this is really starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: You can even get the answer without solving the DE. Look at the dimensions/units! The one and only meaningful answer is C (because $k$ has unit of an inverse time). And of course it is verified via solution of the DE, the for two time stamps $t_1,t_2$ the population doubles if $\ln 2 = k(t_2-t_1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming $P=p$. Solution to the DE is $$ p(t) = A\exp(kt)$$

And you are looking for $\tau$ so that $p(\tau)=2A=A\exp(k\tau)$.

Edit after question of OP:

$$2A=A\exp(k\tau)$$
$$2=\exp(k\tau)$$
$$\ln(2)=k\tau$$
$$\tau=\frac{\ln(2)}{k}$$

Comment: yes that is what I am looking for, but is there another way to express $$ Aexp(kt)$$ so that it is equal to 2A

Comment: You have to solve for $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, you just helped me boost a grade by 20 pts